# COUNTIF numerical substring in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, substring, countif

I have a column of dates in somewhat inconsistent formats, but always ending with the four digit year, like:

```
    May 4, 2021
    Apr. 23, 2021
    Mar 7, 2021
```

if I delete the month and day from every cell, I can count occurrences of years with e.g.

```
    countif(B:B, 2021)
```

However, I'd rather not delete the month and date, but I can't figure how to get COUNTIF to match on the year as a substring. Neither

```
    countif(B:B, "*2021")
```

or

```
    countif(B:B, "*"+2021)
```

work, and I can't figure out why. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`=arrayformula(countif(right(B:B,4),2021))`

Comment: Thanks for this, this works perfectly. At the risk of looking a gift horse in the mouth, can you explain what arrayforumula is doing in that formula? 'countif column B ends with 2021' seems pretty straightforward, but doesn't work without the arrayformula()

Comment: `arrayformula` is used to get the `right` and `countif` functions to calculate down column `B`, rather than having a row-based formula like `=countif(right(B1,4),2021)` in say cell `C1` being dragged down.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

If these are all in date format (as default when these are entered), you can also use `YEAR()` to extract the year, then count:

```
=arrayformula(countif(year(B:B),2021))
```

But if some entries are text, then use this formula instead to convert everything to text first.

```
=arrayformula(countif(right(text(B:B,"mmm dd, yyyy"),4),2021))
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[YEAR()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093061?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you for this -- unfortunately, the data is not consistent, or splitting it into columns would have worked as well. :( One date ("date"), for instance, reads "Flexible, Spring 2021"

Comment: Since there are "text" entries we would have to convert everything to text as well. Edited answer to show updated formula.